# Using multiple database on same CodeIgniter 2.x application and issue with URI Routing

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting, url-routing

I am working on a small web application. In my application I follow the following approach.

Small overview of system

1. The Application will be hosted on the server for example (www.example.com )
2. Clients such as Microsoft, Cocacola, IBM.... etc will sign up. And the clients will access the application by using url like this ( www.example.com/ibm )
3. Each client will have separate database to store their data.
4. If the employees of the client want to login into the system then the url pattern should be like this :

   (www.example.com/ibm/user/login)
   ibm - is the client
   user - is controller
   login - is method of user controller

How to achieve this?

Comment: you have to modify your system/core/router.php _validate_request() method

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please elaborate you answer....

Comment: try yourself and if you got struck anywhere let me know where to help you further

Comment: Can you please reply me with a code example

Comment: Have you considered an approach using a subdomain? meaning that your clients will log into the system using ibm.example.com/login? in this scenario you will need to set your server to allow wildcard subdomain and have the login controller that checks the subdomain when someone logs in and check the info according to the subdomain.

Comment: Lupin, Thanks for your suggestion. But my requirement is to use an extra segment in-spite-of sub-domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Sundar for your advice.
We can achieve this just by little hack in core of codeigniter.

1. Open system/core/router.php in your text editor.
2. Go to Line number 264 .... function _validate_request($segments)
3. Replace $segments[0] with $segments[1]
         OR
4. Add this code at line 270

   $x=$segments;
   $a=1;
   for($i=0;$i<(count($segments)-1); $i++)
   {
       $segments[$i]=$x[$a];
       $a++;
   }