# Using multiple database and issue with URI Routing on same CodeIgniter 3x application

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting, url-routing

I am working on a small web application. In my application I follow the following approach.

Small Overview of system

1. The Application will be hosted on the server for example (www.example.com )
2. Clients such as Microsoft, Cocacola, IBM.... etc will sign up. And the clients will access the application by using url like this ( www.example.com/ibm )
3. Each client will have separate database to store their data.
4. If the employees of the client want to login into the system then the url pattern should be like this :
   (www.example.com/ibm/user/login)
   ibm - is the client
   user - is controller
   login - is method of user controller

I have asked the same question and I fixed and posted the answer:
[CodeIgniter Help - using multiple database on same application and issue with URI Routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27441101/codeigniter-help-using-multiple-database-on-same-application-and-issue-with-ur)

My solution is working fine for CodeIgniter 2.X, but unfortunately not working for CodeIgniter 3.X.

How to achieve this in CodeIgniter 3.X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution.

1. Open system/core/router.php in your text editor.
2. Go to Line number 335 .... function _validate_request($segments)
3. Replace _validate_request function with this code.

   ```
   protected function _validate_request($segments)
   {
       if(count($segments)===1)
       {
           $segments[0]='';
       }
       if(count($segments) > 1)
       {
           $x=$segments;
           $a=1;
           for($i=0;$i<(count($segments)-1); $i++)
           {
               $segments[$i]=$x[$a];
               $a++;
           }
           unset($segments[$i]);
       }
       $c = count($segments);
       // Loop through our segments and return as soon as a controller
       // is found or when such a directory doesn't exist
       while ($c-- > 0)
       {
           $test = $this->directory.ucfirst($this->translate_uri_dashes === TRUE ? str_replace('-', '_', $segments[0]) : $segments[0]);

       if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$test.'.php') && is_dir(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$this->directory.$segments[0]))
       {
           $this->set_directory(array_shift($segments), TRUE);
           continue;
       }
       return $segments;
   }
   // This means that all segments were actually directories
   return $segments;

   }
   ```

Comment: It should be said that it is best not to patch or modify the core of a library unless you are maintaining your own fork. In general it is better to create a subclass of the affected module and then inject that in using whatever DI solution is provided. Does CodeIgniter allow you to do that?